# Broke my script

Tags: batch-file

I tried to get the Ping script also in my Batch script, but now it doesn't work anymore.

```
@echo off 
title Windows Fix Script BETA - Running as Admin check

if "%2"=="firstrun" exit
cmd /c "%0" null firstrun

if "%1"=="skipuac" goto skipuacstart

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs"
exit /B

:gotPrivileges

setlocal & pushd .

cd /d %~dp0
cmd /c "%0" skipuac firstrun
cd /d %~dp0

:skipuacstart

if "%2"=="firstrun" exit


@echo off
title Windows Fix Script 1.1 BETA
goto menu

:menu
cls
echo Please choose an option from the menu.
echo Unsure what the script does? Press H for more information.
echo Choose OPTION J if you don't want to use this script!
echo NOTE: You need to confirm before the script will delete anything!
echo 1. Empty Downloads
echo 2. Empty Temp
echo 3. Empty Recycle Bin
echo 4. IP configuration release
echo 5. IP configuration renew
echo 6. IP configuration complete
echo 7. Information
echo 8. Copyright
echo 9. Exit

:: Note - list ERRORLEVELS in decreasing order
CHOICE /C 123456789 /M "Enter your choice:" 

if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto downloads
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto temp
if ERRORLEVEL 3 goto recycle
if ERRORLEVEL 4 goto ipconfig_release
if ERRORLEVEL 5 goto ipconfig_renew
if ERRORLEVEL 6 goto ipcomplet
if ERRORLEVEL 7 goto information
if ERRORLEVEL 8 goto copyright
if ERRORLEVEL 9 goto exit

:ipconfig_complete
cls
echo This option will release and renew your IP configuration directly.
CHOICE /C YN /M "Enter your choice: " 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO menu
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ipcomplet
:menu
goto menu

:ipcomplet
ipconfig /release
cls
echo We released your IP configuration.
timeout 5 /nobreak
ipconfig /renew
cls
echo We renewed your IP configuration.
timeout 5 /nobreak
goto menu


:ipconfig_release
cls
echo This option will release the IP configuration. Please use the renew option after you runned this script.
CHOICE /C YN /M "Enter your choice: " 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO menu
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO iprelease


:menu
goto menu

cls
:iprelease
cls
ipconfig /release
cls
echo The IP configuration has been released, press any key for the menu.
pause >null
goto menu

:ipconfig_renew
cls
echo This option will renew the IP configuration.
CHOICE /C YN /M "Enter your choice: " 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO menu
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO iprenew


:menu
goto menu

cls
:iprenew
cls
ipconfig /renew
cls
echo The IP configuration has been renewed, press any key for the menu.
pause >null
goto menu

:information
cls
echo This Batch script is written to help you deleting spefic documents from your system.
echo On this moment it works for the Temponary files, the Downloads folder and your Recycle Bin.
echo It also can fix your netwerk connection and check for internet.
echo Prss any key for the menu.
pause >null
goto menu

:copyright
cls
echo This script is written by Mark de Jager to empty different locations on your system. You can use this at own risk but always can ask for support.
echo Twitter: @Vlumondoxa
echo Skype: markdejager.hwi
echo Press any key for the menu.
pause >nul

goto menu

:exit
cls
echo Thank you for using this script, it will close itself after 10 seconds.
timeout 10 /nobreak
exit
:temp


CHOICE /C YN /M "Enter your choice: " 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO reset
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO deltemp


:reset
goto menu

cls
:deltemp
cls
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Windows\Temp\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
cd C:\Windows\Temp
del *.* /q /s
timeout 5
cls
echo We deleted everything in the Temp folder.
echo Note: Please delete the files which aren't deleted yourself.
echo Press any key for the menu.
pause >null
cls
goto menu

:downloads

CHOICE /C YN /M "Enter your choice:" 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto reset
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO deldownloads


:reset
goto menu

cls
:deldownloads
cls
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\USERS\%USERNAME%\Downloads\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
cd C:\USERS\%USERNAME%\Downloads\
del *.* /q /s
timeout 5
cls
echo We deleted everything in the Downloads folder.
echo Press any key for the menu.
pause >null
cls
goto menu

:recycle
CHOICE /C YN /M "Enter your choice: " 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO reset
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO delrecycle

:reset
goto menu

cls
:delrecycle
cls
rd /s /q %systemdrive%\$Recycle.bin
echo We emptied your recycle bin.
echo Press any key for the menu.
pause >null
cls
goto menu
```

Every option is now going for the first option, deleting the downloads. How can I resolve this and make it stable again?

Also how can I add a Ping script which gives a ping to Google and then a pause >null to get back to the menu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto downloads
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto temp
if ERRORLEVEL 3 goto recycle
if ERRORLEVEL 4 goto ipconfig_release
if ERRORLEVEL 5 goto ipconfig_renew
if ERRORLEVEL 6 goto ipcomplet
if ERRORLEVEL 7 goto information
if ERRORLEVEL 8 goto copyright
if ERRORLEVEL 9 goto exit
```

Error levels need to be sorted in descending order.  This is because when errorlevel is 9, then errorlevel 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1 are also true.  You must check highest first.

Comment: Hi it works perfect, can you also help me with the ping script?